# How can I create a pandas dataframe from specific columns of a .txt file?

Tags: python, linux, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a number of text files with a specific format. Each column of the text file is allocated to specific information. There aren't any real delimiters, sometimes the entire set of columns is filled up and thus there isn't always white space. For example

```
1 ALA X   4 80.8 40.6
2 VAL X 234 90.1 42.7
3 VAL X1143 95.2 47.8
...
34ALANX3324100.2345.8
```

Columns 1-2 are dedicated to a straight count from 1-99. Columns 3-6 are dedicated to an identification tag. Column 7 is an modifier tag. Columns 8-11 are a number representing a value in another sequence. The actual meanings don't matter, I'm just explaining to help make it clear what is going on with this .txt file.

In this case I'm interested in columns 1-2 (with values from 0-99) and columns 8-11 (which has values from 0-9999). It is possible that these values sometimes return NaN or letters. I need to take those columns from the .txt file and put them into a pandas dataframe that has two columns. It seems obnoxious to have to add my own delimiters. Is there a way to tell pandas to create a dataframe column using a few of these text file columns?

I am using Python 3.6, pandas v0.23.4, on Linux.

edit: For clarification, when referring to columns of the .txt file I mean to refer to the location of the cursor as you move along horizontally. So the very first character of any line is in column 1, the second character of any line is column 2, the thirteenth character of any line is column 13, etc. When I say column when referring to pandas, I mean the actual column in context of how that word is used in pandas dataframes. Sorry for any possible confusion.

Comment: I don't think so, but parsing your file line by line doesn't seem difficult at all, why don't you just try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this seemed to be easiest to fathom.

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.pdb'):    
newfile = open((filename[:5])+".txt","a+")   
newfile.write('Residue_ID')
temporaryfile = open(filename, 'r')        
for line in temporaryfile: 

    if "CA" in line:                      
        newfile.write(line[23:26])         

    else:                                  
        pass
```

And then use

```
filename[:10] = pd.read_csv((filename[:5])+".txt", columns = [(filename[:10])])
```

to create the dataframe with one column. I'm now just working with dataframes to add them together and what not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the data in your file are in fixed-width columns. With this assumption, I have altered your file to make it acceptable to pandas, like this.

```
 1 ALA X   4 80.8 40.6
 2 VAL X 234 90.1 42.7
 3 VAL X1143 95.2 47.8
34ALAN X3324100.2345.8
```

Then you can read the first and fourth columns in this way.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> names = ['first', 'ignore', 'second']
>>> widths = [2, 7, 4]
>>> df = pandas.read_fwf('hilliard.txt', widths=widths, names=names, index_col=False)
>>> df
   first   ignore  second
0      1    ALA X       4
1      2    VAL X     234
2      3   VAL X1     143
3     34  ALAN X3    3241
```

(Having done this, you could delete the unneeded column.)